# Neo4j - Find movies that share most tags with a particular movie

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This Cypher query I wrote *to find the top 10 movies that share the most number of tags with "Explorers (1985)"* is not returning the desired result. In fact, it runs for a very long time and then stops because there isn't enough memory to complete the computation.

I'm relatively new to Cypher. I would appreciate any help someone could offer.

```
MATCH (m1:Movie {title:"Explorers (1985)"})-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:HAS_TAG]-(m2:Movie)
    WITH size((m2)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t)) as cnt, 
         m2
    RETURN m2, cnt
    ORDER BY in DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your match a bit, since we're traversing the same relationship type twice. As for the tag count, you can either `count(t)`, or simply count the times `m2` occurs in the results, since it will have a row for each tag in common.

Give this one a try:

```
MATCH (:Movie {title:"Explorers (1985)"})-[:HAS_TAG*2]-(m2:Movie)
WITH m2, count(m2) as cnt
RETURN m2, cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm on a large data set, but I think you can minimize loaded nodes by breaking up the query into steps like this...

```
// Get tags on base movie
MATCH (m1:Movie {title:"Explorers (1985)"})-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag)
// Reduce tags to 1 row
WITH m1, COLLECT(id(t)) as tags
// Find only valid Movie-HAS->Tag
MATCH (m2:Movie)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag)
WHERE id(t) in tags AND NOT m2.title = "Explorers (1985)"
RETURN m2, COUNT(t) as cnt
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 10
```